# bigQuery - operation with calculated values

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning

I have a query with two partition by clauses.
I want to know how many times each app was downloaded on average in a day.

```
SELECT date(timestamp) as date, ID, count(*) as cnt_downloads,
sum(cnt_downloads) over (partition by ID) as total_downl, 
count(*) over (partition by ID) as total_appear,
(sum(cnt_downloads) over (partition by ID)) / (count(*) over (partition by ID)) as avg_dowl

FROM [default.download_activity]
where date(timestamp) >= '2016-01-04' and date(timestamp) <= '2016-01-20' 
group by date,two_hour, ID
```

So the query works without the last line before `FROM`. And I know that I could get the value by including simply `(avg (cnt_downloads) over (partition by ID)) as avg_dowl`.

However my question is how I can include an operation of the two subresults of the `partition over` clauses. 
I tried it with and without `()` as well as `[]`. there is always the error that this field is not part of the original database.

Thanks

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't be afraid of using sub queries.

```
SELECT date, ID,
             cnt_downloads,
             total_down1,
             total_appear,
             total_down1/total_appear AS avg_dowl
FROM
  (SELECT date(TIMESTAMP) AS date,
          ID,
          count(*) AS cnt_downloads,
          sum(cnt_downloads) over (partition BY ID) AS total_downl,
          count(*) over (partition BY ID) AS total_appear,
   FROM [default.download_activity]
   WHERE date(TIMESTAMP) >= '2016-01-04'
     AND date(TIMESTAMP) <= '2016-01-20'
   GROUP BY 1,
            2
   )
```

Comment: I'm not afraid, I just don't want to spend twice the money since every query costs some  $2 and they have to run every hour.

Comment: Are you sure the query costs $2 that's a lot? If so you may be have to restructure your tables in table per every day. If you have this issue, please post another question to get help how to reduce costs.

Comment: What does it mean tables in table? As of now a tablerun returns some 300 GB including history from years ago.

Comment: I just tried it with Select - Select and it was almost the same number of GB as in the original query. It means (I didn't know before) that the second select refers financially to the much smaller output table. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding pricing: BigQuery charges for the columnar cost of the initial tables read. There is no extra charge for nested selects. SELECT f FROM (SELECT f FROM (SELECT f ... from (SELECT f from mytable)...))) will charge the byte cost for column f from mytable. You are not charged N*f due to the N nested selects. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#queries